# How do I get a result across 2 tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One is called booking and another one is called room. The columns in booking are: RoomID, startdate, enddate, customerId. The columns in room is: RoomID, size.

I want to select a row from the booking table where a date is between the startdate and the enddate and the size is equal whatever I pass in as an argument. E.g.:

I want to select between 2010-01-31 and 2010-02-25 where size = Large.

EDIT = THIS IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR: `String sqlStatement = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Booking between " + startD + ", " + endD;`

Comment: so what have you written so far?

Comment: @DebosmitRay `String sqlStatement = "SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Booking between " + startD + ", " + endD;`

Comment: can you please add this as an edit to your post?

Comment: How is this related to java?

Answer (score 0):

Use a basic `INNER JOIN` to achieve that.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM booking b INNER JOIN room r USING(RoomID)
WHERE @date_input BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND size = @size_input;
```

Change `@date_input` and `@size_input` to your real input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT booking.*
FROM booking   JOIN room  USING(RoomID)
WHERE column_name BETWEEN startdate AND enddate AND size = @size_input;
```

Comment: in my code startdate and enddate are dates. I dont need the column_name since I am passing the dates in the between clause.