# Whats wrong with the sql statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

`startD` is a date and `endD` is a date and type is a string

```
 String sqlStatement = "SELECT Booking.* FROM Booking INNER JOIN Room USING (RoomID) BETWEEN " + startD + ", " + endD+ " AND RoomSize = " + type;
```

This is my error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN 2016-03-01, 2016-03-01 AND RoomSize = Medium' at line 1
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, what are you trying to do? Check if RoomID is between two dates? I think you may be meaning something like `WHERE booking.date BETWEEN...`.

Comment: What I mean is the user selects 2 dates; startD and endD. The sql statement returns a resultset where the results are in between those dates that the user has entered whilst the RoomSize is equal to what the size the user has specified.

Comment: Yes, but where is the date of the booking stored? You're never saying which field in the database should be between the two dates.

Comment: thanks for the input. My table doesn't contain that column. My table is a based on a booking system in which I have a startDate and endDate column. These columns represent the duration of the booking of a room. Also, I dont have a date column because it wouldn't make sense to incude it, right?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36214362/5830574

Answer (score 0):

see manual [Between Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

replace , with AND in between clause

Answer (score 0):

the SQL statement is not correct, should this be:  String sqlStatement = "SELECT Booking.* FROM Booking INNER JOIN Room USING (RoomID) WHERE someDateColumn BETWEEN " + startD + " AND " + endD+ " AND RoomSize = " + type;

Comment: I have a startdate and enddate column in my table. not a column like someDateColumn as I dont know what to include in it.

Comment: Then instead someDateColumn you should put one of them, e.g.  String sqlStatement = "SELECT Booking.* FROM Booking INNER JOIN Room USING (RoomID) WHERE startDate BETWEEN " + startD + " AND " + endD+ " AND RoomSize = " + type;

Comment: thanks for the help. but I'm still getting an error :   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Medium' in 'where clause

Comment: Do you have a medium column in the table? You should use those columns which are in the Booking or Room tables

Comment: I have a RoomID in my booking and room table if thats what you are talking about?

Comment: @johncena Probably because _Medium_ is not a column but a _string_. Your stmt gives `... and RoomSize=Medium` while it should be `... and RoomSize='Medium'`. But again: _Use prepared statements!_ They avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is wrong:

Try the below one:

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT Booking.* FROM Booking INNER JOIN Room USING (RoomID) WHERE BETWEEN " + startD + " AND " + endD+ " AND RoomSize = " + type;
```

You are missing WHERE clause, also, you are missing an AND(you have put a comma instead) which is required when you provide a range using BETWEEN keyword.

Comment: Can you post in the schema of your tables along with the error message?