# How to retrieve a data between dates

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. A booking table and a room table. In the booking table I have the following columns:   BookingID   StartDate   EndDate CustomerID  RoomID
In the Room table I have  the following columns:    RoomID  RoomSize

I am creating a booking system. I want to be able to query the database where I am able to get a list of rooms that are booked between 2 dates which are also based on size (small, medium or large) types.

E.g. if user clicks on small room and enters dates between 2010-02-02 to 2010-02-25 then 4 should appear as my database contains 4 small rooms that are booked between those dates.

This is what I have so far:

```
 String sqlStatement = "select RoomID from Booking where RoomID in (select Room.RoomID from Room where Room.RoomSize is " + type + ") AND ((Booking.StartDate between "+ startD +" AND " + endD + ") OR (Booking.EndDate between "+ startD + " AND " + endD + "))";
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Medium) AND ((Booking.StartDate between 2016-02-09 AND 2016-02-09) OR (Booking.E' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
```

I am new to SQL and having trouble doing this. Also, is my logic right?
`startD` and `endD` represents the dates that the user has entered and typeOfRoom represent the type of the room the user wants to book; e.g. eithier `Small`, `Medium` or `Large`

Comment: review `Room.RoomSize is " + type + ")`

Comment: type is a string and can either be `Small` `Medium or `Large` based on what the user chose

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36215437/5830574 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/36214362/5830574. Perhaps you should follow the suggestions and ***quote your RoomSize*** like I already told you: Your stmt gives `... and RoomSize=Medium` while it should be `... and RoomSize='Medium'`. Please don't triple-post the very same question.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use string concatenation to insert user-supplied values into SQL, especially for strings. It will leave you open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, and SQL syntax issues. Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Also, replace `is` with `=`.

```
String sql = "select RoomID" +
              " from Booking" +
             " where RoomID in (" +
                       "select Room.RoomID" +
                        " from Room" +
                       " where Room.RoomSize = ?" +
                    ")" +
               " and ((Booking.StartDate between ? AND ?)" +
                 " or (Booking.EndDate between ? AND ?))";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, type);
    stmt.setDate  (2, startD);
    stmt.setDate  (3, endD);
    stmt.setDate  (4, startD);
    stmt.setDate  (5, endD);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The column `RoomSize` is a string, not an int, but +1 for your code.

Answer (score 0):

The date handling look ok I think, but you need to quote the `type` string in the statement. And you should not use `is`, just use normal `=`

```
String sqlStatement = "select RoomID from Booking where RoomID in (select Room.RoomID from Room where Room.RoomSize = '" + type + "') AND ((Booking.StartDate between "+ startD +" AND " + endD + ") OR (Booking.EndDate between "+ startD + " AND " + endD + "))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this statement works? I have replaced the 'is' keyword with '=' operator and put all the variables between "".

```
String sqlStatement = "select RoomID from Booking where RoomID in (select Room.RoomID from Room where Room.RoomSize = \"" + type + "\") AND ((Booking.StartDate between \""+ startD +"\" AND \"" + endD + "\") OR (Booking.EndDate between \""+ startD + "\" AND \"" + endD + "\"))";
```